# Filter output of adb logcat based on thread id

Tags: android, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I am using adb logcat -v threadtime   to get the output in a format that includes time and thread id. I was wondering if there is a way to filter output based on the thread id (tid).

I want to get output from certain threads only, now i can get the thread id but not the filtered output.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
adb logcat -v threadtime | grep 123yourthreadid456
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried this but I want to capture with multiple thread id's.

Comment: Sure, just use adb logcat -v threadtime | grep thread1|thread2|thread3

Comment: Okay, technically, I guess it's more like: adb logcat -v threadtime | grep 'thread1\|thread2\|thread3'

Comment: Works for me, but each time you restart the application you have to go figure out the treadid first - not the best solution.