# Filtering logcat based on process id

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filter output of adb logcat based on thread id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576579/filter-output-of-adb-logcat-based-on-thread-id)

Is it possible to get get output from certain threads only, i am able to get thread id but not the filtered output. I have tried all methods of obtatining logs but unable to filter based on process id.

Comment: How you are trying to fetch logs??

Comment: @Mat this is not a duplicate of that question. pid and tid are not the same, and each requires different approach completely to filter

Comment: Process id: `adb logcat --pid 21345`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse + ADT, you can open the DDMS perspective, active the LogCat Tab, you can input text like this “pid:18467” into the InputTextBox in the top of the panel.
Then the LogCat will filter all the message for the app which the pid is 18467。